# Build a Boat Form Plugin

Tags: plugins, forms

I am putting together a quote for a custom wordpress website for a client that specializes in the Pontoon business. I am fairly familiar with Wordpress, HTML, CSS, and a very basic JS. The client requested a custom build a boat plugin that will give users the option to spec out their boats and then populate into a wishlist that can be emailed to a dealer or printed out.

Initially I was just thinking of doing this all in a form myself or hiring someone who can do this who is experienced with Javascript (I am not) because I don't want to waste time trying to muck this together.

Any ideas, suggestions or plugins that I might be able to use to achieve this without hiring someone?

Thanks!

Comment: What you need to do is break this down into smaller more numerous chunks of work, and keep repeating until you're able to estimate each part. Then, add it all up. This is **spec work**, and you should either be charging the client for it, or asking the person who would be building it.

Comment: As a side note, breaking it down will also identify the more discrete requirements you need from what will be built, allowing you to assess 3rd party plugins as potential options, as well as identifying gaps in your knowledge which you can then ask about on sites like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to buy the Gravity Forms plugin in order to accomplish this.

http://www.gravityforms.com/

Yes, there are other form plugin options such as Contact Form 7 but I can assure you (and everyone here) that the Gravity Forms plugin is hands down the option for this task.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Johann. I will look into this! I'd love to figure out a way to do this myself instead of having to outsource it.